# Sleep() in android

Tags: android, multithreading, sleep, runnable

I am working on a mini game for Android. I am using this code to create a 3 minute timer that pauses when the game is paused:

```
class update extends Thread{
    @Override
    public final void interrupt(){
        super.interrupt();
        }
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try{
            while(true){
                sleep(50);
                iTime++;
                if(iTime>=3600)
                    bEnd = true; //finish

                postInvalidate();
                }
            }catch(InterruptedException e){         
                }  
    }
}
update thread = null;

3600 = 20*3*60
```

The timer finishes in the emulator within about 5 minutes, and in the Galaxy Tab after about 1.5 minutes.

Why doesn't it always take 3 minutes? How do I ensure that it finishes within 3 minutes?

Comment: optimization maybe?  why not just find out the current time, set a timer to expire in 3 minutes and complete when the timer goes off?

Answer (score 5):

How about using the [Android CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) class?

```
// 30 second countdown
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```

Comment: Why not have an `isPaused` boolean flag which gets set on `onPause` and `onResume` and check this in the timer?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you doing in the postInvalidate() but maybe you can do something with AlarmManager and a service. You could create a task that will run in 3 minutes from now, and it will execute the service which, in your case, will invalidate the game.

I've seen many questions that were trying to handle timeouts with sleep method and I believe Android doesn't guaranteed that it will work that way.

Post back if you need help creating the service or running something with AlarmManager. I answered a question about it a couple of days ago.